# How to print out current url on Magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: geturl

I'm looking for a way to get current URL from the file "view.phtml". 
I've tried these 2 differents ways. None of them do print the entire product URL. Worst, the second way crashes...

```
/*1*/ Mage::log(__METHOD__ . '()'.Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'));
/*2*/ Mage::log(__METHOD__ . '()'.Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
```

Don't hesitate to provide code snippets as I'm new in Magento.

Comment: If you're needing to sniff the current URL you have defined a solution to a problem that either shouldn't exist or you're approaching incorrectly. Often these can be solved by understanding how layout and layout handles work.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial to suggest me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into Mage::app()->getRequest() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also need to take note you're on a 4 year old Magento version. So things you read now can possibly be since a newer version.

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri()` should provide the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

The following prints out current product URL. This code should be inserted in template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```